# Filters Background

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to insert filters in background image in fabric.js?

```
  function backchange(img)
    {   
        var imag = img.src;  
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(imag, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
      width: canvas.width,
      height: canvas.height,
      // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top'
    });
    }
```

I can add filters in the images selectable, but how put filters on the images background that is not selectable?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

write a callback, to replace `canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)`, and refer to `canvas.backgroundImage` to add filters to the image.

```
  function backchange(img) {   
      var imag = img.src;  
      canvas.setBackgroundImage(
        imag,
        function() {
          canvas.backgroundImage.filters.push(new fabric.Image.Filters....);
          canvas.backgroundImage.applyFilters();
          canvas.renderAll();
        },
        {
          width: canvas.width,
          height: canvas.height,
          // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
          originX: 'left',
          originY: 'top'
        }
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a base: http://fabricjs.com/image-filters

You can target the background this way (just basing this on the: function applyFilter) and setting Sepia on the background.

```
obj = canvas.backgroundImage;
obj.filters[3] = new f.Sepia();
obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```